# How to display only one of duplicates and count them to show how many in parentheses

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, mapping

I have a json file for products.

```json
{
    "product": [{
        "id": "butter2",
        "name": "Y 200 G",
        "img": "dolor sit amet",
        "price": "79,90",
        "brand": "Y"
    }, {
        "id": "butter",
        "name": "Y 500 G",
        "img": "",
        "price": "62,90",
        "brand": "Y"
    }, {
        "id": "honey3",
        "name": "x 600 G",
        "img": "dolor sit amet.",
        "price": "49,90",
        "brand": "X"
    }, {
        "id": "honey2",
        "name": "x 400 G",
        "img": "dolor sit amet",
        "price": "56,90",
        "brand": "X"
    }, {
        "id": "honey",
        "name": "x 800 G",
        "img": "dolor sit amet.",
        "price": "57,50",
        "brand": "X"
    }]
}
```

I want to make search filter with options with checkboxes for brands. How can i display same brands only for once and how many of them in parentheses side by that brand.

I use map() to list brands. But don't know how to eliminate duplicates.

```
        mysublinks.product?.map((item: any) => (
                  <div className="ml-6 mt-2">
                    <input
                      id="default-checkbox"
                      className="w-4 h-4 text-orange-300 accent-orange-300  border-gray-300 rounded  ease-in mr-2  "
                      type="checkbox"
                      key={item.uniqueId}
                    />

                    <label key={item.uniqueId}>{item.brand}</label>
```

result should look like => "checkbox "X (3)
"checkbox "Y (2)

I search whole net but im a beginner. So any help will be useful. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

To not get any duplicates you could convert the brands into a set:

```js
const productSet = new Set(product.map(p => p.brand))
```

Now you can loop over productSet (`productSet.forEach(product => {})`) and create check boxes inside the loop.

You'll still need to loop over the whole array to list all the items.